# Percentage Calculations on Lists

Tags: python

I have created a quiz system which tests the user on two different topics. They are can choose whih topics they would like to do and a difficulty they wish to complete it in. If they get the question correct they get a point if they don't it will display the correct answer.

I am struggling to calculate the percentage based on the user's correct answers. For example, I have came up with "percent = score/100 x 100" which doesn't work. Any suggestions of calculating the percentage from these lists?

```
t = input("Choose 'a' for arithmetics or 'g' for german:")
d = input("Choose 'e' for easy , 'm' for medium , 'h' for hard:")


arithQeasy = [
    ("What is 4 + 4? Choose 1 or 2: 1) 8 2) 7","1"),
    ("What is 16 + 16? Choose 1 or 2: 1) 26 2) 32","2"),
    ]


arithQmedium = [
    ("How many 6's in 36? Choose 1, 2 or 3: 1) 6 2) 12 3) 3","1"),
    ("What is the Square root of 100? Choose 1, 2 or 3: 1) 50 2) 100 3) 10","3"),
    ("What is 0x1000? Choose 1, 2 or 3: 1) 1000 2) 0 3) 100","2"),
    ]

if t == "a" and d == "e":
    questions = arithQeasy

elif t == "a" and d == "m":
    questions = arithQmedium

for question, answer in questions:
    userInput = input(question + '')
    if userInput == answer:
       score +=1
       print ("correct your score is:",score)
    elif:
       print ("Incorrect the anseer is:",answer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work. Note there are a couple of issues with your code snippet:

- The `elif` in the `for` loop needs to be an `else`.
- You need to initialize `score` to zero before entering the `for` loop.

I've fixed these problems and added some code at the end illustrating how to compute the percentage of correct answers, as you asked how to do:

```
...
score = 0
for question, answer in questions:
    userInput = input(question + '')
    if userInput == answer:
       score += 1
       print("correct your score is:", score)
    else:
       print("Incorrect the anseer is:", answer)

percent = round((score / len(questions)) * 100, 2)
print('percent right: {}%'.format(percent))
```

**Explanation**

This works because a percentage is "a number or ratio expressed as a fraction of 100" (from the Wikipedia article on [percentage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage)), so the expression calculates the ratio of right answers, `score`, to the total number of questions, `len(questions)`. It then multiples that by 100 since percentages always express this ratio as a "fraction of 100".

I also added a call to [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)—which wasn't strictly necessary—to limit the number of digits after the decimal point to two, so long numbers like `6.666666666666666%` would get converted to `6.67%`. Technically this makes the final value computed slightly less accurate, but I doubt that matters here.

Comment: The code does work, but I do not understand how the percentage is calculated. Could you please explain the code for calculating the percent? Thankyou

Comment: Thankyou Martin :))